# Tried to copy multi-session DVD - got "k3b does not support copying multi-session DVD or blu-ray disks" what to do?

Tags: 16.04, iso, dvd

I have 4.7 Gb DVD-disc with some archival data and I want to copy it to other DVD disk (or read to ISO-file). K3b shows that it has 3 sessions:

[image: k3b - 3 sessions]

Usually I use K3b for disc writing and copying. But in current case it fails on "Creating Image" stage with message "k3b does not support copying multi-session DVD or Blu-ray disks":

[image: k3b fail]

Brasero tries to copy the last session (about 14 Mb).

What else should I try? How can I copy my multi-session disc using Ubuntu?

Comment: What kind of DVD disk is it? Where does it come from? How was it created? Have you tried with the risky `dd` or with `ddrescue`? Could it be that the DVD drive has not got the ability to read this kind of drive in the complete way, that is necessary for making an image or a cloned copy?

Comment: Currently I do not have this disk. It was written on some medical DICOM device. I was able to access files on it. I can't find solution in Ubuntu, so I copied it on MS Windows with Roxio (do not remember the name exactly). How should I copy such disk next time in Ubuntu with some GUI method?

Comment: It is difficult to test what might work, when you haven't got the DVD disk.